# singapore visa expired but passport is vilid

Tags: pakistani-citizens, singapore, visa-expiration

I am travel singapore to Kuala Lumpur 24-Jul and exit date is 26-Jul but my question is that my singapore visa vilid date is 26-Jul  so i can travel ?

Comment: i am not citizen of Singapore. i travel to pakistan to Singapore and Singapore to   Kuala Lumpur. so i can travel it or not?

Comment: Could you edit your question please - it's very hard to read as it stands. Separate sentences are useful.  If you can include all information IN your question (not in comments) that'd help too.

Answer (score 3):

You are OK to travel.

A few countries consider the visa expiry date to *not* include that date, so that if their visa expires on 26 July, the last day you can travel is 25 July. Singapore is not one of these countries.

Singapore considers its visa expiry date to include that day. So if the visa expires 26 July, then the last day you can travel is 26 July, until the end of the day at midnight.

You should also note that, unlike most countries, Singapore visa expiry indicates the last date that you can *enter* the country. The amount of time you can stay in the country may be longer than the visa expiration, and will be shown on the visit pass that Singapore immigration officers stamp into your passport.